# WellKnownServiceTypeEntry's ObjectType is null

Tags: c#, remoting

I have a .NET remoting server which has multiple registered well known types:

```
<wellknown type="VS.WorkingClass, WorkingClass" objectUri="WorkingClass.rem" mode="SingleCall"/>
<wellknown type="VS.BrokenClass, BrokenClass" objectUri="BrokenClass.rem" mode="SingleCall"/>
```

When I execute `RemotingConfiguration.Configure(configFile)` and loop through `WellKnownServiceTypeEntry` instances from `RemotingConfiguration.GetRegisteredWellKnownServiceTypes()`, entry for `WorkingClass` has its ObjectType set but `BrokenClass` hasn't. Both classes are included as project references in the server project and I get no error messages. Any ideas what could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a really stupid mistake on my part. type attribute of course needs information in format "type, assembly" and my classes were located in assemblies which were not named `WorkingClass` or `BrokenClass`. Unfortunately RemotingConfiguration didn't throw an exception about not finding the class. Maybe there is a reason for this but I'm now just happy that I can continue on with my work.